# how multiple azure apps can use the same jwt token for authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory, jwt, single-sign-on

We have two RestAPIs which are hosted in azure Kubernetes. These APIs use Azure Apps for authenticating users through SSO. We are planning to get the token from one api (which is connected to its own app) and use it in the other API (which is connected to another app). Is there a way to achieve this goal? currently the token generated in api1 is not valid in the api2 and vise versa. For APIs we are using this configuration. Hope my question is clear, please let me know if I need further clarification.

User impersonation and scope (more details are [here](https://intility.github.io/fastapi-azure-auth/single-tenant/azure_setup))

We are using access_token and oath2
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/301754/use-the-same-auth-token-for-multiple-apps) is a very similar to mine  but we are not planning to access Azure resources, so not sure if the answer to this question still holds for our problem.

I came across [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/industry/training-services/microsoft-community-training/rest-api-management/service-to-service-authentication) but not sure if this is the best solution or even a solution.

To clarify, all the azure apps, and APIs are in one tenant.

Comment: Where are you planning to do the token validation - in UI or API apps? Are you using MSAL for authentication/authorization?

Comment: Token validation happens inside the restapi (fastapi), we are using oath2, thanks

Comment: If token validation happens in the API, you can acquire tokens for different resources (which are your API applications) in the UI itself and send those tokens to the API. Are you using MSAL in your UI application? MSAL makes it really simple to acquire tokens for different resources.

Comment: Thank u so much for your time and consideration, please Let me simply my question, I cannot talk about the UI as it has been developed by another team,

Comment: Aah...I see. Not sure if this helps but the way I see it is that it would be the responsibility of the UI app to acquire token for the appropriate API and then send that token along with the request to that API. At the most what you can do in the API app is to check if the scope included in the token matches with that of the API. If the scope  does not match, you simply return `401` error code back to the UI.

Comment: But this is an interesting idea, maybe api 2 can extract scope from the received token  that has been generated by api1, I do not know how to include scope in the access_token but maybe there is a way, and then api2 can validate the token by calling the app1.  I guess it is similar to what you are saying except the responsibility is with the api not ui, however, thanks alot and not sure if there is a better way to do this

Comment: This depends on whether the second application needs the user context and whether the second application trusts the first application and the connection between app 1 and app 2 is secure. If app 1 and app 2 are developed separately then I would use On-Behalf-of Auth (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/on-behalf-of). If they trust each other and the connection between them is secure then you can directly pass the token OR use another form of service-to-service auth (i.e. cert auth)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I agree with @*Jack Jiang*, you can make use of On-Behalf-of flow to achieve your scenario.

I created three Azure AD Applications for sample `webapi1` `webapi2` `webapi3`.

In `webapi1`, I added below Api permissions:

[image]

In  `webapi2`, I added below Api permissions:

[image]

I generated **access token for `webapi1`** using below parameters via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:webapi1ClientId
scope:api://webapi2ID/webapi2.read
grant_type:authorization_code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
code:code
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

Using the above generated access token, I tried to call `webapi3` Api like below:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:webapi2ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer
assertion:access_token_generatedabove
requested_token_use:on_behalf_of
scope:api://webapi3ID/webapi3.read
```

[image]

**Otherwise**, you can make use of [Client Credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to call the Apis.

**Reference:**

[Microsoft identity platform and OAuth2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)